Type that is a concatenation of all the keys of an object
Suppose I have this type:
type MyObject = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
};

I would like to create a type like so:
type Concatenator<T extends Record<string, string>, S = `/`> = `TODO HERE`;

That results in the following accepted values:
// I don't care about the order, so either one is fine, or both is fine too
const concatenated: Concatenator<MyObject> = 'one/two';
const concatenated: Concatenator<MyObject> = 'two/one';

How would one proceed? I know how to do something like this with nested properties, but I am unable to grasp this one.

What do you expect Concatenator<MyObject> to be? 'one/two' | 'two/one'? I can write that, but then Concatenator<{a:0,b:1,c:2,d:3,e:4,f:5,g:6,h:7}> will explode the compiler. Things like this just do not scale. Is that what you want? Are you always going to be using just a few keys?

This is only for learning purposes, but the idea it originated from is translating strings with both a key, and some arguments, for instance errors.minlength#min|8#actual|2

Are you saying you're okay with a solution that scales badly?

Although if it's possible to have a fixed order to ease the compiler (so juste one/two but not two/one for instance), it doesn't bother me !

How would you determine the fixed order? TS doesn't give order to keys.

@jcalz If it's impossible to determine the order, I am okay with a solution that scales badly (the purpose is to learn advanced typings)

Then does this playground link work how you expect? If so I'll write an answer or find a duplicate. If not, what's missing?

It looks perfect, thank you, you can make an answer !

CAVEAT This is just for exploration of the type system and not something you should use in real production systems. You are asking to take the union of keys in an object type (via the keyof operator) and concatenate them in every possible order. This scales very badly with the number of keys, as the number of permutations grows super-exponentially. So this will be fine for three keys, hard to read for five keys, hard on your computer for seven keys, and impossible for nine keys.
Okay, let's break this into parts.

Given a union type T, let's write a generic AllPermutations<T> utility type that evaluates to a union of tuples of every possible ordering of the union members:
type AllPermutations<T, U = T> =
  T extends any ? [U] extends [T] ? [T] : [T, ...AllPermutations<Exclude<U, T>>] : never;

This is a distributive conditional type over T, so it means that T is split into its union members, and each member is evaluated separately before the result is joined together. The U type parameter is really meant to be a copy of the full union T that does not get split into members. So U is the full union, while T is each member of the union.  If [U] extends [T] is true, it's because the union U has one member (the [+] is to prevent distribution over the union in U) so there's just one permutation, the one-tuple [T].  Otherwise we recurse, and prepend T to the result of AllPermutations<Exclude<U, T>>. That is, we remove T from the union U and get all those permutations.
Let's test that:
type KeyPerms = AllPermutations<keyof MyObject>;
// type KeyPerms = ["one", "two"] | ["two", "one"]
type ExamplePerms = AllPermutations<0 | 1 | 2 | 3>;
/* type ExamplePerms = 
  [0, 1, 2, 3] | [0, 1, 3, 2] | [0, 2, 1, 3] | [0, 2, 3, 1] | [0, 3, 1, 2] | 
  [0, 3, 2, 1] | [1, 0, 2, 3] | [1, 0, 3, 2] | [1, 2, 0, 3] | [1, 2, 3, 0] | 
  [1, 3, 0, 2] | [1, 3, 2, 0] | [2, 0, 1, 3] | [2, 0, 3, 1] | [2, 1, 0, 3] | 
  [2, 1, 3, 0] | [2, 3, 0, 1] | [2, 3, 1, 0] | [3, 0, 1, 2] | [3, 0, 2, 1] | 
  [3, 1, 0, 2] | [3, 1, 2, 0] | [3, 2, 0, 1] | [3, 2, 1, 0] */

Looks good (but you can see how badly it scales).

Now, let's write a utility type Join<T, S> where T is a tuple of string literal types and S is a string literal separator:
type Join<T extends string[], S extends string, A extends string = never> =
  T extends [infer F extends string, ...infer R extends string[]] ?
  Join<R, S, [A] extends [never] ? F : `${A}${S}${F}`> : A

This is also a distributive conditional type, which helps when T is a union, so the result will also be a union.  Basically we're using variadic tuple types to split T into its first element F and the rest of the tuple R, and recursing (using an accumulator type parameter A so that the type is a tail-recursive conditional type). If T is empty we've hit the base case and just return the accumulator A. Otherwise we need to append F to A and recurse. Conceptually that's `${A}${S}${F}`, but if the accumulator A is empty then we'll get a separator at the beginning.  So we have to do an additional check if A is empty (I made it never) as [A] extends [never] ? F  `${A}${S}${F}`.
Let's test that:
type JoinEx = Join<["a", "b", "c", "d"], "-">;
// type JoinEx = "a-b-c-d"
type JoinEx2 = Join<KeyPerms, "/">;
// type JoinEx2 = "one/two" | "two/one"

Also looks good.

Finally we can make Concatenator out of AllPermutations and Join:
type Concatenator<T extends Record<string, string>, S extends string = `/`> =
  AllPermutations<keyof T> extends infer AP extends string[] ?
  Join<AP, S> : never

Conceptually you'd just write Join<AllPermutations<keyof T>, S> but TypeScript tries to simplify that in a way that prevents it from working. I've used conditional type inference to "copy" AllPermutations<keyof T> into a new type parameter AP (and to constrain it to string[] so Join accepts it). Then Join<AP, S> works.
Finally, let's test it:
type MyObject = {
  one: string;
  two: string;
};

type Z = Concatenator<MyObject>
// type Z = "one/two" | "two/one"

let concatenated: Concatenator<MyObject>;
concatenated = 'one/two';
concatenated = 'two/one';
   
type W = Concatenator<{ a: '0', b: '1', c: '2', d: '3' }>;
/* type W = "a/b/c/d" | "a/b/d/c" | "a/c/b/d" | "a/c/d/b" | "a/d/b/c" | "a/d/c/b" | "b/a/c/d" | 
"b/a/d/c" | "b/c/a/d" | "b/c/d/a" | "b/d/a/c" | "b/d/c/a" | "c/a/b/d" | "c/a/d/b" | "c/b/a/d" | 
"c/b/d/a" | "c/d/a/b" | "c/d/b/a" | "d/a/b/c" | "d/a/c/b" | "d/b/a/c" | "d/b/c/a" | "d/c/a/b" | 
"d/c/b/a" */

Looks good, and for the last time: it scales very badly.
Playground link to code
